# Drawing image on canvas in firefox on first load or reload with ctrl+f5 does not work

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

My problem is that the image is not drawn on the canvas on the first load of the document in firefox (version 34). It works in IE.

I created a minimum sample page to illustrate my problem. You should be able to reproduce by creating a HTML file with the code, use any png file and load the file in firefox. Width and height are the width and height of my picture, just use your image size.

I added the img tag before the canvas so that the image should be loaded before the javascript code executes. But the canvas only draws the image if I press F5 again after the first load. Pressing Ctrl+F5 and the image is gone. F5 back again... You get the picture. If the cache is emptied the drawing does not work.

Does anyone know if I can prevent this in firefox (as it works in IE, didn't test chrome)? Did I overlook something I should do before drawing?
Maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="ball.png"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var internal_image = new Image();
        internal_image.src = "ball.png";
        internal_image.width = 18;
        internal_image.height = 19;
        context.drawImage(internal_image, 10, 10);
    </script>
</body>
```

This is only a one file sample for illustration. Actually I am using jquery and the code is executed in the

> $(document).ready

function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the `drawImage` function inside the image's `load` function to ensure that the image is actually loaded before trying to draw it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var internal_image = new Image();
internal_image.src = "ball.png";
internal_image.width = 18;
internal_image.height = 19;

internal_image.addEventListener("load", function() {
  context.drawImage(internal_image, 10, 10);
}, false);
```

Comment: That works. Do you happen to know why the original code does not work in firefox but in IE?

Comment: Most likely it was luck that it was working in IE :) Most likely the image just managed to load before calling `.drawImage()`, which explains why it worked with FF from cache too.