# Canvas does not show text the first time

Tags: jquery, firefox, canvas, fonts, textbox

Hi I have some troubles with text on canvas. 
I have several inputs type text and for each of them, I need to create canvas with their texts. When inputs have default texts, texts are not shown on canvas the first time. I need to refresh before seeing texts in firefox (and texts with fonts applied in chrome incognito mode).
I try to do solutions I found here :[Drawing image on canvas in firefox on first load or reload with ctrl+f5 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334856/drawing-image-on-canvas-in-firefox-on-first-load-or-reload-with-ctrlf5-does-not/49033611?noredirect=1#comment85071920_49033611) or here: [Firefox won't draw to canvas on first visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158624/firefox-wont-draw-to-canvas-on-first-visit) but I cannot make them work.
Any idea for me? thanks

Here is my simplified code:

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {

    if(typeof(pgc)!='undefined'){
        somefunction(); //call this first because canvas need #preview width and height.
        setTimeout(create_pgc_text_container, 200, "non ajax");
    }


    function create_pgc_text_container(mode){
        console.log(mode);
        $('[id$="-field"]').each(function ()
        {
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            var field_settings=pgc.text_settings[id];
            var field_datas=$.parseJSON(field_settings);
            var angle="rotate("+field_datas.angle+"deg)";
            $("#text_panel").append('<canvas id="'+field_datas.container+'" class="text_field jtextfill" style="font-size:'+field_datas.size+'px;top:'+field_datas.top+'%;transform:'+angle+';left:'+field_datas.left+'%;"><span></span></div>');

            var text = $(this).val();
            var current_field_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var current_color = $('#'+current_field_id).parent('.textfield-box').parent('.pgc-single-option-wrap.textfield').find('.pgc-textfield .pgc-textfield-color [data-field]').data('color');
            var current_font = $('#'+current_field_id).parent('.textfield-box').parent('.pgc-single-option-wrap.textfield').find('.pgc-textfield .pgc-textfield-font .font-selector[data-field]').val();
            var current_font_link = $('#'+current_field_id).parent('.textfield-box').parent('.pgc-single-option-wrap.textfield').find('.pgc-textfield .pgc-textfield-font .font-selector option:first').data('font');

            var image = new Image;
            image.src = current_font_link;
            $.when(current_font_link.load)
            .done(function () {
                image.onerror = function() {
                    console.log(current_font_link);
                    add_text_on_preview(text,current_field_id, current_font, current_color);       
                };
            });

            add_text_on_preview(text,current_field_id, current_font, current_color);
            // call again because some troubles in firefox loading first time.

            somefunction();

        });          
    }

    function add_text_on_preview(text, field_id, font, color){
        font = font || '';
        color = color || '';
        var field_settings = pgc.text_settings[field_id];
        var field_datas = $.parseJSON(field_settings);
        //console.log(field_datas.default_font);

        var mycanvas = $('#'+field_datas.container);
        mycanvas[0].width = $('#preview').width();
        mycanvas[0].height = $('#preview').height();

        var ctx = mycanvas[0].getContext('2d');

        var fontfamily = function() {
            var field_font;
            if (font == '') {
                if ( field_datas.default_font !== null ) {
                    field_font = field_datas.default_font;
                } else {
                    field_font = ' sans-serif';
                }
            }
            else
                field_font = font;

            if ( field_font.indexOf("://") != -1 ) {
                //console.log('found');
                fontUrlArray = field_font.split("=");
                if ( fontUrlArray.length >= 1 ) {
                    return fontUrlArray[1].split('+').join(' ');
                }
            }
            else {
                //console.log('not found', field_datas.font);
                return field_font;
            }

        }();

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas[0].width, mycanvas[0].height);

        field_datas.size = ( field_datas.size !== null && ( field_datas.size !== undefined && ( field_datas.size !== '' ) ) ) ? field_datas.size : 12 ; 
        //ctx.font = field_datas.size + 'px ' + font;
        ctx.font = field_datas.size + 'px ' + fontfamily;
        //console.log(ctx.font);

        if (color == '') 
            ctx.fillStyle = field_datas.default_color;
        else
            ctx.fillStyle = color;

        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.textAlign = field_datas.text_align; 

        var positionTopText = ($('#preview').height() * field_datas.top)/100;
        var positionLeftText = ($('#preview').width() * field_datas.left)/100;
        //console.log(positionLeftText, positionTopText);

        ctx.fillText(text, positionLeftText, positionTopText);
    }


});

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Without your code is tough to know what is wrong.

Comment: I update my post with my code

Answer (score 1):

Finally I use webfont.js and some jquery promises. But I was forced to check more than one time if all dom element (tests) are loaded. This following waitForEl function , i found it [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/7890303)

```
     var waitForEl = function(selector, callback) {
      if (jQuery(selector).length) {
        callback();
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          waitForEl(selector, callback);
        }, 100);
      }
    };

    WebFont.load({
        custom: {
            families: customFonts
        },
        google: {
            families: googleFonts
        },
        active: function() {
            console.log('webfonts loaded');
            waitForEl(inputs, function() {
              // here add my text element to canvas
            });
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before. It's the same scenario with external fonts that it is with images, you are calling it before they load. I saw this hacky solution somewhere and it worked for me (still trying to find the source so I can link it here).

Do something like this:

**HTML:**
`<p id="loadMe">Must include Text</p>`

(Put the above tag before `<script>` and `<canvas>`)

**CSS:**

```css
@font-face {
  /*Define the font here*/
}

#loadMe {
  font-family: [Insert whatever it is];
}
```

If the font loads on canvas first try, then you can experiment with how to hide the loader element! You may need to use `style.fontFamily` in your js file to ensure that it doesn't re-load the font from the same location.

Comment: Finally I use webfont.js and some jquery promises. But I was forced to check more than one time if all dom element (tests) are loaded.